# What is the Clojure equivalent of Scala's zipWithIndex?

Tags: clojure

Scala [`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Seq) has the `zipWithIndex` method:

> `def zipWithIndex[A1 >: A, That](implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Seq[A], (A1, Int), That]): That`
>
> Zips this sequence with its indices.
>
> returns: A new sequence containing pairs consisting of all elements of this sequence paired with their index. Indices start at 0.
>
> Example: `List("a", "b", "c").zipWithIndex = List(("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("c", 2))`

What is the equivalent function in Clojure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clojure's [`map-indexed`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed) will give you an indexed list of elements in a collection.

```
user=> (map-indexed vector "foo")
([0 \f] [1 \o] [2 \o])
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jmargolisvt answered `map-indexed` is a good solution.

As your example got index inverted with collection items, you can always compose with reverse:
`(map-indexed (comp reverse list) ["a", "b", "c"])`

Or map over two sequences:
`(map list ["a", "b", "c"] (range))`